# significance of nginx upstream_connect_time logged as an empty value vs hyphen

Tags: nginx, openresty

I've noticed for 499 client timeouts the upstream_connect_time nginx logged is sometimes an empty value, and sometimes a hyphen '-'.

I'm guessing this difference in how this field is logged means something - but I haven't seen this explained in the documentation. Would be interesting to know.

The upstream connection in this case is over https. Currently my best guess is perhaps this distinguishes between when a TCP connection was made (without completing the SSL handshake) vs no connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a request is unable to reach an upstream server or a full header cannot be received, the variable is set to zero

In case of internal error while connecting to an upstream or when a reply is taken from the cache, the variable is set to -