# Why is $upstream_response_time in add_header a hyphen?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Given `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 8000;

        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:8001;

            add_header X-Trip-Time    $request_time;
            add_header X-Process-Time $upstream_response_time;
        }
    }
}
```

Running:

```
python3 -u -m http.server 8001 > app.log 2>&1 & sudo nginx
```

followed by:

```
curl -i localhost:8000
```

shows these two headers:

```
X-Trip-Time: 0.001
X-Process-Time: -
```

I've seen [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/917212/significance-of-nginx-upstream-connect-time-logged-as-an-empty-value-vs-hyphen) related question, which says this:

> In case of internal error while connecting to an upstream or when a reply is taken from the cache, the variable is set to -

But my upstream server is successfully connected to as shown by `cat app.log`:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2021 19:41:44] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

What is the cause for `$upstream_response_time` equaling `-`, yet `$request_time` works as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received [this answer](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,290674,290678#msg-290678) on the nginx mailing list:

> That's because response headers are sent before the
> $upstream_response_time is known: it is only known when the response
> is fully received from the upstream server, including the response
> body, and this happens after the response headers are sent to the
> client. If you want to return something in the response headers,
> consider the $upstream_header_time variable instead
> (http://nginx.org/r/$upstream_header_time).

I couldn't find anything in the documentation about how nginx buffers *responses* (can only find documentation for requests) and whether it can be configured, but sure enough changing `$upstream_response_time` to [`$upstream_header_time`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_header_time) is working and the times are very close when looking in the logs, atleast when the response body size is miniscule such as in my case.